# Override itervalues of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, built-in

I have a class `TimedCache(dict)` that for each value keeps a `tuple(value, timestamp)`.

How can I override the `itervalues` function to return only the `value` and ignore the `timestamp`. Still I want this to be an iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I want to know if there is a better one :)

```
def itervalues(self):
    for value, timestamp in super(TimedCache, self).itervalues():
        if time.time() - timestamp <= self.ttl:
            yield value
```

Comment: Looks good, so this question is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, you can unpack `value` in the for loop for improved readability: `for value, expiration in ...: if time.time() - expiration > self.ttl: yield value`.

Comment: Not sure if you want the application logic of excluding expired values in your itervalues implementation.

Comment: @RobFoley Agree, I actually delete them, but this was just a snippet

Comment: @chepner Thanks for feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create your own [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) (an abstract base class from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)) for more consistency.

The only methods to implements are `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`.

They are used by the following methods (already implemented):
`__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `iterkeys`, `iteritems`, `itervalues`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`.

Here is an example for a dictionary that filters items based on an arbitrary criteria:

```
class FilteredDict(MutableMapping):

    def accept(self, key):
        # Only accept items with interger key and string value
        return isinstance(key, int) and isinstance(self[key], str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dict[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.dict[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.dict:
            if self.accept(key):
                yield key

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(dict(self))
```

Example:

```
>>> fd = FilteredDict({1: 'a', 2: 'b',  '3': 'c', 4: 4})
>>> fd.dict
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 4: 4, '3': 'c'}
>>> fd
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
>>> list(fd)
[1, 2]
>>> list(fd.itervalues())
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: this looks a bit complicated. I want this to be very fast and memory friendly

Comment: It is just as memory friendly as a `dict`. The time complexity is also the same except for the `__len__` method. The problem with your solution (subclassing `dict`) is that you will have to override `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `iterkeys`, `iteritems` and `__iter__` in order to be consistent, which is probably more painful than using the implementation provided by `MutableMapping`.